# [Angular][Unit test] this.isDateInstance is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I just started to write some unit test on my app. It's also my first test. I never wrote.

I have a form with some field and a field with date picker using angular-material.

But i have this error `TypeError: this.isDateInstance is not a function`

```
I use 
Angular : 5.2.11
Material-Angular : 5.2.5
```

I have this test :

```js
describe('Component : FormFillInfoPatientComponent', () => {
  let element;
  let de;
  let component: FormFillInfoPatientComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormFillInfoPatientComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatMomentDateModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatIconModule,
        // MatNativeDateModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader}
        })
      ],
      declarations: [
        FormFillInfoPatientComponent,
        ControlMessagesComponent,
        DisplayInputDateLocalePipe,
      ],
      providers: [
        FormValidationService,
        DateAdapter,
        // NativeDateAdapter,
        MomentDateAdapter,
        FormBuilder,
        HttpClient,
        {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: function (http: HttpClient) {
            return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
          },
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(inject([DateAdapter], (dateAdapter: DateAdapter<any>) => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormFillInfoPatientComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.patientAccount = new PatientAccount();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    element = fixture.nativeElement;      // to access DOM element
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    dateAdapter.setLocale('fr');
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('form invalid when empty', () => {
    expect(component.patientForm.valid).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should disabled button next', () => {
    let btnNext = element.getElementsByClassName('btn-next');
    expect(btnNext.disabled).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('should disabled button next', () => {

    const fields = component.fields;
    fields.forEach((field: { name: string, validators: Validators[] }) => {
      let currentDomField = component.patientForm.controls[field.name];
      expect(currentDomField.valid).toBeFalsy();
      field.validators.forEach((validator: Validators) => {
        let errors = currentDomField.errors || {};
        if (validator instanceof Validators.required) {
          expect(errors['required']).toBeTruthy();
        } else if (validator instanceof Validators.email) {
          currentDomField.setValue('test');
          expect(errors['pattern']).toBeTruthy();
        }
      });

    });

  });
});
```

My component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'dgk-form-fill-info-patient',
  templateUrl: './form-fill-info-patient.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-fill-info-patient.component.scss'],
})
export class FormFillInfoPatientComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  //....

  patientForm: FormGroup;

  fields = [
    {name: 'email', validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]},
    {name: 'firstName', validators: [Validators.required]},
    {name: 'lastName', validators: [Validators.required]},
    {name: 'maidenName', validators: []},
    {name: 'phone', validators: []},
    {name: 'gender', validators: [Validators.required]},
    {name: 'dateOfBirth', validators: [Validators.required]},
  ];

  constructor(
    private readonly _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    // private readonly _monitor: MonitoringService,
  ) {
    const formFields = this.fields.reduce((obj, field) => {
      let ret = ['', field.validators];
      obj[field.name] = ret;
      return obj;
    }, {});

    this.patientForm = this._formBuilder.group(formFields);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dateNow = moment();
  }

  // ....
}
```

```html
<div fxLayout="column" fxFill="" fxFlex="">
  <form fxLayout="column" [formGroup]="patientForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="{{'GENERIC.FORM.EMAIL' | translate}}"
             type="email"
             [(ngModel)]="patientAccount.email"
             name="email"
             formControlName="email"
             required>
      <mat-error>
        <dgk-control-messages [control]="patientForm.controls.email"></dgk-control-messages>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    //.....
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput
             [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker"
             (focus)="myDatepicker.open()"
             [(ngModel)]="patientAccount.dateOfBirth"
             formControlName="dateOfBirth"
             [max]="dateNow"
             placeholder="{{'GENERIC.FORM.DOB' | translate}} (ex: {{ '1999-12-31T00:00:00' | displayInputDateLocale }})">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
      <mat-error>
        <dgk-control-messages [control]="patientForm.controls.dateOfBirth"></dgk-control-messages>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>


    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" class="mat-padding">
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent" matStepperPrevious class="margin btn-previous">
        <mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon>
        {{'GENERIC.BUTTONS.BACK' |translate}}
      </button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext class="margin btn-next" [disabled]="!patientForm.valid">
        {{'GENERIC.BUTTONS.NEXT' |translate}}
        <mat-icon>arrow_forward</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

I think i have imported all required modules or providers, but i don't know why this error happen.

```
TypeError: this.isDateInstance is not a function
at DateAdapter.deserialize (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js?:689:35)
at MatDatepickerInput.set [as max] (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/datepicker.es5.js?:2370:68)
                                      at updateProp (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:12876:37)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:12587:19)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14150:20)
at checkAndUpdateNode (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14093:16)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14986:76)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14927:13)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/FormFillInfoPatientComponent.ngfactory.js:573:5)
                                        at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (webpack:////myPath/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14912:21)
```

Have you any idea ? or the same problem ?

Thx

Comment: Try providing all the dependencies of your module into your testbed. Given the error, I would suggest `MatDateAdapter` or `MomentDateAdapter`, based on what you chose to use.

Comment: I tried, i import all module 
MatFormFieldModule,
        MatMomentDateModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,


And providers: 
NativeDateAdapter,
        MomentDateAdapter,
        DateAdapter,

nothing changed same error

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] with this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template

Comment: Thanks for yours answer. I started this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-ebxhvb?file=main.ts but i have some error for importing third librairie.

Comment: In `HelloComponent`, remove `declare const moment;`, uncomment `import * as moment from 'moment';
`, and replace `dateNow = moment();
` with `dateNow = moment.now();
`

Comment: Thanks you ! 
This is the template with same error from my project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-ebxhvb

Comment: I've corrected your initial issue by applying the correct modules to your test (don't use `moment` and `native` at the same time) : [here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-8q8tcq?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts). Now you have to resolve the other issue, I'm getting on it too.

Comment: Next, you have to remove `[(ngModel)]` from you input (you already have a `formControlName` attribute), and add `MatInputModule` to the testbed. After that, it should work (but it doesn't in the stackblitz because of internal errors).

Comment: Thanks your for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

I got same error : `TypeError: this.isDateInstance is not a function`

In my case the problem was with saturnDatePicker.

I have imported two DateAdapter :

```
import {DateAdapter as DateAdapterT,} from 'saturn-datepicker'; 
import {DateAdapter} from '@angular/material/core';
```

Providers :

```
  providers: [
    ...providers,
    //DateAdapterT, //revmove this one and it works
    DateAdapter,
    ConfigsService

  ],
```

Double providers as the same time was also the problem.
Thanks @Maryannah for the clue :)